# yii 1 CJuiDatePicker inside custom widget

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

I create new `widget` like this:

```
class Schedule extends CWidget
{

    public $address = null;
    public $order = null;//order

    public function init()
    {
        if(isset($this->order))
            $this->address = $this->order->address;
    }

    public function run()
    {
       $city = City::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'is_active = 1','order'=>'name ASC'));
       $this->render('my_schedule',array('city'=>$city));
    }
}
```

and `view` for this `widget`:

```
<?php 
$form = new CActiveForm();
$form->id = 'checkout-form';

$form->enableAjaxValidation = true;
$form->clientOptions = array(
'validateOnSubmit' => true,
'validateOnChange' => false);

$order->address = $address;
?>
<?php if(is_array($city) && count($city) > 0) : ?>
        <section class="persent70">
            <p>
                <?php
                    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                                    'model'=>$order,
                                    'attribute'=>'delivery',
                                    'name'=>'delivery',
                                    'options'=>array(
                                    'showAnim'=>'slide',
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                                'class'=>'form-control',
                                                'id'    => 'delivery',
                                            ),
                                        ));
                                    ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($order, 'delivery'); ?>
            </p>
```

In this case calendar doesn't open, but when i use `CJuiDatePicker` in a simple  view this `datepicker` works fine.

Comment: Can you try to put the widget code before `$form = new CActiveForm();`? Maybe there's a problem with id's or something. I will test your code at home, maybe i will find the problem.

Comment: I tried, the same problem, seems like the library of CJuiDatePicker doesn't work in this place.

Comment: Can you post the full view-code?

Comment: link to file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk9wz0rqzeabdp0/view.txt?dl=0

Comment: I tested, none of the zii\jui components in this view doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$this->getController()->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(....));`.

Comment: Where i should add this one?I'm new in yii))

Comment: Instead of `$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker'...`

Comment: What does the browser console say? Any JS-Error's?